# Twitter Streaming API. How async process tweets in php?

Tags: php, twitter

In common, code should collect tweets, process it and store in db some statistics. I use phirehose lib for Twitter Stream API, so it streaming tweet constantly. As far as I understand I can't parse tweets in the same process, so I should parse tweets in other process, so phirehose lib should get tweets and store it somewhere or queue them in memory for other process (or processes), which will parse them and store in db. So I don`t want reinvent a wheel, so may there is some snippets of code or some lib, that allow such data processing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this quite late, but others might find it helpful. While Phirehose might work, it looks quite fragile. It doesn't implement a full HTTP client, but rather manually sends headers and attempts to parse the response.

I'd recommend to use a proper HTTP client. You don't *need* non-blocking I/O if you want to consume just a single stream, but it can be helpful, because you can write the results somewhere else while continuing to consume Twitter's stream.

One such client is [Artax](https://github.com/amphp/artax), that supports streaming responses out of the box. It can easily be combined with a [streaming JSON parser](https://github.com/kelunik/streaming-json). You can [find a full example](https://github.com/kelunik/streaming-json/blob/eabf02a1a1141011efceefa81cde546913dce799/examples/twitter-streaming.php#L62-L78) in the repository of the mentioned JSON parser, you might want to use a separate package for the request signing.

That combination will already parse the emitted stream, you just have to do what you need to do with the tweets, e.g. sum up your statistics and write them somewhere. If you don't want to block the stream consumption while doing so, you'll need something that supports non-blocking I/O to write your data.

```
/** @var Response $response */
$response = yield $client->request(
    (new Request($uri, "POST"))
        ->withHeader("authorization", $authorization)
);

if ($response->getStatus() !== 200) {
    exit(1);
}

$parser = new StreamingJsonParser($response->getBody(), true);

while (yield $parser->advance()) {
    // do whatever you want with your tweet here
    var_dump($parser->getCurrent());
}
```